# ARB Subscription creation in Authorize.net using bank account

Tags: authorize.net

First of all, I am just asking that is it possible to create ARBsubscription using bank account. Almost all the example showing using credit card. But I want to do it using bank account. I am using "anet_php_sdk". Although there is also ARB with credit card in the sample code. But I changed a bit like -

```
<?php
    require_once 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php';

    define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "YOURLOGIN");
    define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "YOURKEY");

    $subscription                          = new AuthorizeNet_Subscription;
    $subscription->name                    = "PHP Monthly Magazine";
    $subscription->intervalLength          = "1";
    $subscription->intervalUnit            = "months";
    $subscription->startDate               = "2017-05-12";
    $subscription->totalOccurrences        = "12";
    $subscription->trialOccurrences        = "1";
    $subscription->amount                  = "45.00";

    $subscription->bankAccountAccountType  = "CHECKING";
    $subscription->bankAccountRoutingNumber= "121042882";
    $subscription->bankAccountAccountNumber= "123456789123";
    $subscription->bankAccountNameOnAccount= "Test Test1";
    $subscription->bankAccountEcheckType   = "WEB";
    $subscription->bankAccountBankName     = "Bank of Earth";

    /*$subscription->creditCardCardNumber    = "4007000000027";
    $subscription->creditCardExpirationDate= "2018-10";
    $subscription->creditCardCardCode      = "123";*/

    $subscription->billToFirstName         = "test";
    $subscription->billToLastName          = "test1";

    // Create the subscription.
    $request = new AuthorizeNetARB;
    $response = $request->createSubscription($subscription);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    die();
    $subscription_id = $response->getSubscriptionId();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a bank account with subscriptions. [Page 22 of their guide](http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/ARB_guide.pdf) lists all of the available fields to do so.

In your example you have both a credit card and bank payment account which is invalid. You need to remove the credit card lines of code.

Comment: thanks john for reply. I thinnk you did not notice credit card info commented. Besides this is everything right. I have followed this doc to get params. But after call the API no response coming.

Comment: When looking at the SDK documentation its example did not look like your code. Are you using the latest SDK? And have you followed its examples?

Comment: Hi i am using "anet_php_sdk". and i have used "echeck" payment using it. However can you give me the link of SDK.